# Parse two Numbers from Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to parse number from Text Line in SQL.

My Text line is as:

[image]

I want to retrieve values of First & second as column using SQL as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that you can then use as a procedure on select:

```
DECLARE @row VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @row = 'First:87.85 Second:87.88 mtr'
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @result = 
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@row,'mtr',''),'First:',''),'Second:','')))

SELECT
SUBSTRING(@result,0,charindex(' ',@result)) As First,
SUBSTRING(@result,charindex(' ',@result),LEN(@result)) AS Second
```

This treats one row at a time.

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/ZDXP73328)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of the strings is fixed, one fairly simple way is to use a common table expression with lots of `charindex` columns to get the start and end positions of the numbers, and then select from that cte with `substring`.

First, create and populate sample table(**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T (col) VALUES
('First:87.85 Second:87.85 mtr'),
('First:8 Second:82 mtr'),
('First:85 Second:8 mtr'),
('First:7.5 Second:87 mtr');
```

The cte:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  col As String,
            7 As FirstStart,
            CHARINDEX(' Second', col) As FirstEnd,
            CHARINDEX(' Second', col) + 8 As SecondStart,
            CHARINDEX(' ', col, CHARINDEX(' Second', col)+1) As SecondEnd
    FROM @T
)
```

The select statement:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(String, FirstStart, FirstEnd - FirstStart) As First,
        SUBSTRING(String, SecondStart, SecondEnd - SecondStart) As Second
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
First   Second
87.85   87.85
8       82
85      8
7.5     87
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/QPKBZZ64326)